# How could I vectorize this for loop?

Tags: ios, c, arm, vectorization, neon

I have this loop

```
void f1(unsigned char *data, unsigned int size) {
    unsigned int A[256] = {0u};      
    for (register unsigned int i = 0u; i < size; i++) {
        ++A[data[i]];
    }
   ...
```

Is there any way to vectorize it manually?

Comment: There are some tricks you could do, but this code pretty much looks like a textbook example of code a compiler can optimize.

Comment: How is this question related to ARM, NEON, or IOS?

Comment: @FUZxxl I try to implement this for iOS app. I need this loop ran fast. And I suppose vectorization might help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since multiple entries in `data[i]` might contain the same value, I don't see how this could be vectorized simply since there can be race conditions. The point of vectorization is that each element is independent of the other elements, and so can be computed in parallel. But your algorithm doesn't allow that. "Vectorize" is not the same thing as "make go faster."

What you seem to be building here is a histogram, and iOS has built-in, optimized support for that. You can create a single-channel, single-row image and use `vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8` like this:

```
void f1(unsigned char *data, unsigned int size) {
    unsigned long A[256] = {0u};

    vImage_Buffer src = { data, 1, size, size };
    vImage_Error err = vImageHistogramCalculation_Planar8(&src, A, kvImageDoNotTile);
    if (err != kvImageNoError) {
        // error
    }
    ...
}
```

Be careful about assuming this is always a win, though. It depends on the size of your data. Making a function call is very expensive, so it can take several million bytes of data to make it worth it. If you're computing this on smaller sets than that, then a simple, compiler-optimized loop is often the best approach. You need to profile this on real devices to see which is faster for your purposes.

Just make sure to allow the compiler to apply all vectorizing optimizations by turning on `-Ofast` (Fastest, Aggressive). That won't matter in this case because your loop can't be simply vectorized. But in general, `-Ofast` allows the compiler to apply vectorizing optimizations in cases that it might slightly grow code size (which isn't allowed under the default `-Os`). `-Ofast` also allows a little sloppiness in how floating point math is performed, so should not be used in cases where strict IEEE floating point conformance is required (but this is almost never the case for iOS apps, so `-Ofast` is almost always the correct setting).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This approach works great. And it is a little faster than simple loop unrolling or other tricks if input data is uniformly dispersed (I have experimented).

Comment: Even if `data[i] == data[i+1]`, you can map them to different locations and combine the results afterwards.  I think the problem here is that you would need something like AVX's gather/scatter functionality, but superscalar execution is not going to be much slower (if at all).  See marko's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The optimisation the compiler would attempt to do here is to parallelize `++A[data[i]]`

It cannot do so because the contents of A depend on the previous iteration of the loop.

You could break this dependancy by using one frequency array (`A`) per way of parallelism, and then computing the sum of these at the end. I assume here you've got two ways of parallelism and that the `size` is even.

```
void f1(const unsigned char * const data, unsigned int size) {
    unsigned int A0[256] = {0u};
    unsigned int A1[256] = {0u}; 


    for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < size /2u; i++) {
       ++A0[data[2*i]];
       ++A1[data[2*i+1]];
    }

    for (unsigned i=0u; i < 256; ++i){
        A0[i] = A0[i] + A1[i];

    }
}
```

Does this win you much?  There only one way to find out - try it and measure the results. I suspect that the Accelerate framework will do much better than this, even for relatively small values on `size`. It's also optimised at run-time for the target architecture.

Compilers are pretty smart, but there are things you can do in C or C++ to help the compiler:

- Apply `const` wherever possible: It's then obvious which data is invariant.
- Identify pointers to non-overlapping memory regions with the `restrict` (`__restrict` in C++) qualifier. Without knowing this, the compiler must assume a write through one pointer potentially alters data that could be read with another. `clang` will in fact generate run-time checks and code-paths for both the overlapping and non-overlapping case, but there will be limits to this, and you can probably reduce code-size by being explicit.

I doubt the `register` qualifier for `i` makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, `register` is useless in this situation. Thanks